# Converting Chromedriver to FirefoxDriver with selenium in python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I tried to make some automation saving pages into PDF file.
The problem is that Chromedriver has some bugs with changing print sizes. No matter how I adjust it, it just save the page with default size.

I've asked it to selenium github, and they said it works with Firefox while it doesn't work with Chrome driver.

I haven't used selenium with Firefox. And clearly, it doesn't support 'add_experimental_option' as well.

I also tried to look for how to print - save to PDF from the scratch with Firefox, but most of the codes are using pyguiauto, and clicking it.

Can I convert this codes to Firefox, geckodriver?

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{
        "id": "Save as PDF",
        "origin": "local",
        "account": ""
    }],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2,
    "mediaSize": {
        "height_microns": 355600,
        "width_microns": 215900,
        "name": "NA_legal",
        "custom_display_name": "legal"
    },
    "isCssBackgroundEnabled": True,
    "isHeaderFooterEnabled": True,
}


prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState' : json.dumps(settings)}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
driver.get('page')
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @KJ Ah, Thanks for the explanation KJ. It was so close to get into a goal.
I should find other workaround then...

Comment: @KJ The thing is, I don't want to use virtual keys. I'll look a way with Chromedriver to adjust the default size of prints.